# ajax calendar hours and minutes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, datepicker

Is there an extension or some method in the ajax control toolkit associated with the ajax calendar which can create specific DateTime object even with specific selected hours and minutes? Or perhaps some other easily managable datepicker?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already found something. I keep using my ajax calendar and add a [jquery clockpicker plugin](http://www.jnathanson.com/index.cfm?page=jquery/clockpick/ClockPick). Can recommend.